# Adding together xValue totals using dimple.js

Tags: d3.js, charts, dimple.js

I have a bar graph showing three separate bars. What I want to do is add together the total xValues for each one and display that total elsewhere on the page. Is there a way to do this with dimple?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dimple is just for simplifying the chart drawing, it leaves everything else to d3. Therefore you can use d3.sum on your underlying data to get the value you are looking for.  So if your data looks like this:

```
data = [
    { "xValue": "A", "yValue": 14 },
    { "xValue": "A", "yValue": 13 },
    { "xValue": "B", "yValue": 11 },
    { "xValue": "C", "yValue": 24 }
];
```

You could do:

```
svg.append("text")
    .attr("x", 100)
    .attr("y", 100)
    .text(d3.sum(function (d) { return d.yValue; }));
```

This will place some unformatted text showing 62 at 100,100 in your svg.

You can position and apply formatting etc to this using the appropriate d3 methods.

Comment: Hi thanks for responding. I'm not sure where to put your code, if I add it in I get the error message "d3.append is not a function".

Comment: sorry it should have been svg.append.  I've updated the answer

Comment: sorry, its no longer giving an error but all I get is 0. is there anything else I need to do?

Comment: My post summed X but it should have been Y. If you copied that it may be the problem. Otherwise you'll need to post a sample of your code and data.

Comment: its ok i got it working. i was needing the value to be stored so I can call it elsewhere on the page so the d3.sum part was what I needed. Thanks for the help. much appreciated.